# fuelPHP read config from db

Tags: php, database, fuelphp

I have table in DB with global settings for site. I want to load these parameters when fuelPHP is starting and use it in all controllers. table columns is id|setting_name|setting_value. I used codeigniter and it was coded as helper. I called function site_settings('parameter') and i got result. How to do this in fuel?

Comment: *what a stupid question :D* (I'm sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to build a class to get it to work with Fuel.

Creating a model might make sense since it's got built in hooks to a database.
Check out Model_Crud or ORM.

http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/model_crud/introduction.html
http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/intro.html

Both of these will you can access your database and update and create settings if needed.

Then you will want to add it to the config file to have it autoloaded.

http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/configuration.html

You could also extend the core Config class:
http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/config.html
http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/extending_core.html

which will give you access to the cor config methods which include the basic getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Controller, eg GlobalController
And extend the other controllers to the Global one.

Then in GLobalController you create a `before()` function. In other words this function will be **executed** before the rest.

```
public function before() {
    parent::before();
    $this->globalstring = "MyGlobalString"; 
}
```

Now, every controller who have extended the `GlobalController` can detect the `$this->globalstring` string or any other thing that you put in that function.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most transparent solution would be to extend the Config class to add DB as a supported backend.

http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/3104/dbconfig-store-your-app-specific-config-setting-in-a-db-rather-than-loads-of-config-files, altough old, might give you some pointers on how to do it.

You should not use ORM for this, as that would require to many dependencies. Use regular DB calls instead.